# Take certain edges in Dijkstra (or DFS)

Tags: graph, dijkstra, depth-first-search

i have a question about Dijkstra and/or DFS. 
Let's assume I have a graph, with several nodes and edges. Now i want to find a Path from Node A to Node B. On this way i have to take certain Edges, for example the Edge (C,D).

Edit:

Sorry if it was a little bit unclear. My question is : I want a path from A to B. Is there a Path so that all edges {a,b}, {b,c}... and so on are taken? I'm interested if that's possible with dfs. And if thats also possible with Dijkstra under the same constraint if i want the shortest path from A to B and some edges {a,b}, {b,c} in the graph are needed to be taken. Also the graph is directed.

Help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What is the question exactly ?

Comment: To my understanding, if an edge `{a,b}` is required in the shortest path from `s` to `t`, the solution would be to find a shortest path from `s` to `a` and a shortest path from `b` to `t` and combine the paths with `{a,b}` in the middle.

Comment: What excatly do you mean by 'initially unweighted'? If this is the case, what is a shortst path? One with a minimal numnber of edges? If so, the edge weight would be `1` implicitly.

Comment: I don't get why dijkstra is mentioned here, if the aim is to find any path in an undirected and unweighted graph.

Comment: Sorry if it was a little bit unclear. My question is : I want a path from A to B. Is there a Path so that all edges {a,b}, {b,c}... and so on are taken? I'm interested if that's possible with dfs. And if thats also possible with  Dijkstra under the same constraint if i want the shortest path from A to B and some edges {a,b}, {b,c} in the graph are needed to be taken. Also the graph is directed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a list of the all the edges that you want to make sure must be navigated.
2. Perform a DFS starting from the source.
3. Everytime you pass though an edge that's in the list, mark is as "traversed".
4. When you reach the destination, check if all the edges in the list are marked as traversed.
   a.) If yes, goal state reached.
   b.) Else, backtrack and unmark each edge in the list while passing                through them.